# Modify keys in ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have a ndarray that looks like this:

```
array([[ -2.1e+00,  -9.89644000e-03],
       [ -2.2e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [ -2.3e+00,   2.33447000e-02],
       [ -2.4e+00,   5.22411000e-02]])
```

Whats the most pythonic way to add the integer `2` to the first column to give:

```
array([[ -0.1e+00,  -9.89644000e-03],
       [ -0.2e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [ -0.3e+00,   2.33447000e-02],
       [ -0.4e+00,   5.22411000e-02]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

To add 2 to the first column only, do

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([[ -2.1e+00,  -9.89644000e-03],
                  [ -2.2e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
                  [ -2.3e+00,   2.33447000e-02],
                  [ -2.4e+00,   5.22411000e-02]])
>>> x[:,0] += 2 # : selects all rows, 0 selects first column
>>> x
array([[-0.1, -0.00989644],
       [-0.2,  0.        ],
       [-0.3,  0.0233447 ],
       [-0.4,  0.0522411 ]])
```

---

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([[ -2.1e+00,  -9.89644000e-03],
                  [ -2.2e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
                  [ -2.3e+00,   2.33447000e-02],
                  [ -2.4e+00,   5.22411000e-02]])
>>> x + 2
array([[-0.1,  1.99010356],
       [-0.2,  2.        ],
       [-0.3,  2.0233447 ],
       [-0.4,  2.0522411 ]])
```

Perhaps the [Numpy Tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-4c1d53fe504adc97baf27b65513b4b97586a4fc5) may help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... unfortunately that's now the output I'm looking for. I updated my question to be more clear.